# Content management system

Tags: web, service, content-management-system, product

I'd like to ask is it smart enough to ship a web service/product without creating any CMS?

I mean in order to ship it faster and get some feedback from users it will be smart from my point of view to ship it w/out CMS and build it as you go but Im afraid from technical point of view - would it create any big problem that would be painful to solve?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you expect from the website. Should it be only a one-time web presentation, I think it might be okay to ship it without a CMS. I would also consider it fine if you didn't want to run a database for whatever reason (as most of the CMSs use database).

If the product is meant to be more complicated, it's definitely easier to start with CMS than to hack it in the product later.

However, if you decided for the latter way, you might find [CouchCMS](http://www.couchcms.com/) interesting. Though I haven't tested it myself, it looks very promising and easy to inject into an existing website.